# Powershell loop through folders, create file in each folder

Tags: loops, powershell

I'm trying to recursively loop through all the folders in a directory, then do something within each directory. Create a text file, for example.

I can get all the subfolder into a variable like so:

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
```

However, I can't seem to create a file within each subdirectory - the files are instead created in the top directory. This doesn't work:

```
$folders | ForEach-Object { New-Item -ItemType file -Name "$_.txt" -path $_}
```

That throws up an error that the directory is not found or that the path is too long.

How do I do something in each subdirectory of nested folders?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {New-Item -ItemType file -Path "$($_.FullName)" -Name "$($_.Name).txt" }
```

Basically, the `Get-ChildItem` command returns a sequence of `DirectoryInfo` objects. The `FullName` property contains the full path, whilst `Name` just contains the name of the leaf directory.