# Do not move file if extension is missing using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

There is multiple folders inside a directory. i want to move those folders to a  other directory only if a particular file "preview.jpg" is available inside the sub-folder. if extension is not available do not move the folder. inside the folder there could be other extension files. i have very basic knowledge about powershell. i could call children item and use something like this but this way it will not work. it will move all the folders. if one folder has preview.jpg it will run the move command.

```
if (Test-Path -Path "C:\*" -Include preview.jpg -PathType leaf)
{
Move-Item -Path "C:\*" -Destination "C:\Move" -Force -Verbose;
}
```

Comment: I have removed your invalid tags, and mentions of language/interpreter unrelated to your provided code. This is not a code request service, so you can only request help for a specific issue with your provided code.

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to iterate over the directories: [Powershell loop through folders, create file in each folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543052/powershell-loop-through-folders-create-file-in-each-folder). You would then check if the file "preview.jpg" exists in each directory.

Comment: Also, you might want to use the `-WhatIf` parameter: [The PowerShell WhatIf Parameter: Looking Before you Leap](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-whatif/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath (Get-ChildItem -File -Path C:\*\preview.jpg).DirectoryName `
          -Destination C:\Move -Force -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) `-File -Path C:\*\preview.jpg` finds all files inside *immediate subdirectories* of `C:\`
- `(...).DirectoryName` returns the full paths of these files' *directories*, i.e. the full paths of the subdirectories of interest.
- [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) is capabable of receiving *multiple* paths via its `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` parameters, so all of the subdirectories whose paths are passed are moved to directory `C:\Move`.

  - Important:

    - Be sure that the target directory already exists.
    - If it is itself a subdirectory of the directory tree being examined, be sure that it doesn't itself contain a `preview.jpg` file.

Note that the command assumes that at least *one* subdirectory of interest exists.

If that isn't always true, capture the results of the `Get-ChildItem` call in a variable first (`$subdirs = (Get-ChildItem -File -Path C:\*\preview.jpg).DirectoryName`) and use an `if` statement around the `Move-Item` call (`if ($subdirs) { Move-Item -LiteralPath $subDirs ... }`).

Comment: @Luuk, my answer states "Note that the command assumes that at least one subdirectory of interest exists." This is apparently not true in your case (`preview.jpg` files are only present in _sub-subdirectories_, so to speak). The last paragraph of the answer also states how to handle the case when _no_ subdirectory matches.